# After updating ruby to 2.7.1 rspec tests throws error `Bundler::GemfileError for status code 4 but Bundler::GemfileError is already registered`

Tags: rspec, bundler, ruby-on-rails-5.2, ruby-2.7

- using Rails 5.2.4.3
- Mac OSX Catalina 10.15.6

After updating ruby to 2.7.1 (via rvm) ran `rspec spec` and received error:

```
Trying to register Bundler::GemfileError for status code 4 but Bundler::GemfileError is already registered
    # /Users/----/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.1@xmx/gems/bundler-2.1.4/lib/bundler.rb:7:in `require_relative'
    # /Users/----/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.1@xmx/gems/bundler-2.1.4/lib/bundler.rb:7:in `<top (required)>'
    # ./config/boot.rb:4:in `require'
    # ./config/boot.rb:4:in `<top (required)>'
    # ./config/application.rb:1:in `require'
    # ./config/application.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
    # ./config/environment.rb:2:in `require_relative'
    # ./config/environment.rb:2:in `<top (required)>'
    # ./spec/spec_helper.rb:18:in `require'
    # ./spec/spec_helper.rb:18:in `<top (required)>'
    # ./spec/models/activation_spec.rb:1:in `require'
    # ./spec/models/activation_spec.rb:1:in `<top (required)>
```

- switching to global gemset resolved the issue, but using default gemset continued to throw the error.
- uninstalling and reinstalling bundler did not solve the issue (ensured bundler v 2.1.4)
- I could run by using `bundle exec rspec spec` (but wanted to actually solve the problem)

Comment: noted several days later setting up a new machine, when I started sidekiq server also caused the issue (not related to rspec tests). Solution below fixed the problem.

Comment: Completely new install of Ruby 2.7.1 same issue... same fix

Answer (score 9, accepted):

A lot of the discussions I found on this error were pretty old. Then, finally stumbled upon this recent github discussion:

- https://github.com/rubygems/rubygems/issues/3551

Running the following solved my issue:

`gem update --system 3.0.8 && gem update --system`

Note: To run update without installing documentation

`gem update --system 3.0.8 --no-document && gem update --system --no-document`

Answer (score 2):

```
gem update --system
```

it works for me

Answer (score 0):

In my case I came to this page because of the same error on Github Actions workflow. And the fix `gem update --system 3.1.2 && gem update --system` (for Ruby 2.7.6) was not enough.

The sample workflow yaml file has following lines,

```yaml
- name: Install Ruby and gems
  uses: ruby/setup-ruby@v1
  with:
    bundler-cache: true
```

which installs Ruby and gems together. I was able to get out of this error by removing `bundler-cache: true` and running `bundle install` over again.

```yaml
- name: Install Ruby and gems
  uses: ruby/setup-ruby@v1
  with:
    ruby-version: 2.7.6
- name: Upgrade rubygems and reinstall gems
  run: |
    gem update --system 3.1.2 && gem update --system
    gem update bundler
    bundle install
```

Then my `rspec` test passed without error.

Answer (score 0):

update gem to higher version ,as your version is 2.7

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).